# How do you bind state to an element in angular without ngFor?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering how you would be able to do something like this(it's pug instead of html):

```
.collapsible
      a(mat-list-item routerLink="/sites/user-gruppen" routerLinkActive="link-active") User & Gruppen
        i.material-icons((click)="changeSomeVariableForThisElement()") arrow_right
      .collapsible-body([@dropDownAnimation]="someVariable")
        a(mat-list-item routerLink="/sites/user-gruppen/user" routerLinkActive="link-active") User
.collapsible
      a(mat-list-item routerLink="/sites/hilfe" routerLinkActive="link-active") Hilfe
        i.material-icons((click)="changeSomeVariableForThisElement()") arrow_right
      .collapsible-body([@dropDownAnimation]="someVariable")
        a(mat-list-item routerLink="/sites/hilfe/faq" routerLinkActive="link-active") FAQ
```

The relevant parts are `[@dropDownAnimation]` and `(click)`

With ngFor it would be easy, as we could just use let's say `item` in the case of `ngFor="let item of items"` and then have something like item.state which we manipulate.

I have been searching for 2 hours now and I can't find any documentation on this, maybe I just don't know what to search for, as I am relatively new to angular.

How would I be able to change e.g. `someVariable.state` for only the current element clicked but not for all elements in there?

Comment: Instead of declaring a list of items, declare a single item ? I don't really see your issue there.

Comment: Sorry I can see how it's unclear, I added another element to my pug to hopefully make my problem clear. I don't want several "changeSomeVariableForThisElement()" functions for each list item with different variables, but just a single one which will be able to save the "state" of each of my list items individually... Like the ngFor which saves a change on "(click)" for only the current item element for example. Does that make sense?

Comment: the code you posted should work. `someVariable` can be something such as `items[0]`

Comment: So all of your items would have the same state ?

Comment: No each individually, I added a question at the end of the answer, maybe now it's clear? Haha really sorry for confusing